# "return this" in a covariant trait that return actual type

Tags: scala, covariance, self-type

This was probably asked before, but I have this problem:

```
trait Container[+A] {
  def a: A

  def methodWithSideEffect() = {
    // perform some side effecting work
    this
  }
}

class IntContainer(val a: Int) extends Container[Int]
```

How do I have the `methodWithSideEffect` in `IntContainer` return an `IntContainer` instead of a `Container[Int]`? I would also want not to add any parameter to the `Container` trait, at least from the API user point of view. Note that I did make a workaround with an implicit:

```
implicit class MyContainer[A <: Container[_]](c: A) {
  def methodWithSideEffect(): A = {
    // perform work
    c
  }
}
```

However, I am quite sure there is some way to do this more elegantly.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can do this with a self type:

```
trait Container[+A] { self =>
  def a: A

  def methodWithSideEffect(): self.type = {
    // perform some side effecting work
    this
  }
}

class IntContainer(val a: Int) extends Container[Int]
```

...

```
val x: IntContainer = new IntContainer(42).methodWithSideEffect()
```

Or simply with `this.type`:

```
trait Container[+A] {
  def a: A

  def methodWithSideEffect(): this.type = {
    // perform some side effecting work
    this
  }
}

class IntContainer(val a: Int) extends Container[Int]
```

Comment: Or simply `this.type`

Comment: Thank you, I was sure it was an easy question :)